# Typescript types fuzzy match to match key

Tags: typescript

```
type k = {
  'name': number;
  'age': string;
};

type m = FuzzyMatch<k, 'ge'>;
```

How can i write a function FuzzyMatch which can fuzzyMatch 'ge' to 'age' and return true;

Even chatgpt 3.5 can not give the right answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fuzzy match" here?  Please [edit] to explain what criteria your desired algorithm uses, and/or give more test i/o.  I mean, given your question, I don't know which of the following should match "age" and which should not: "rage", "angle", "gae", "AGE", "g", "carnage", "ageless".  Once you do this and the information is enough to answer the question, we can vote to reopen it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type can be build by using literal types to decompose the key K into three parts - Prefix, S and Suffix, where

- `Prefix` is the part of the key before the specified string
- `S` The specified string you want to match
- `Suffix` The part of the key after the specified string

If `K` contains specified string - use resulting type `K`, otherwise return `never`

```js
type k = {
  'name': number;
  'age': string;
};

type FuzzyMatch<T, S extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends `${infer Prefix}${S}${infer Suffix}` ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type AgeOrName = FuzzyMatch<k, 'a'> // 'age' | 'name'

type Age = FuzzyMatch<k, 'ge'> // 'age'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA1lC8UDeBYAUFKByAdgQwFsIsAuKHAVwICMIAnAbnUyzwHNiyBnYOgSxxsmaAL7D0oSFABiFAF5yQAWTzAAxgAsAPABUANFADKUCAA9gEHABMuUHv0EA+BMmZQA2gGkoA2BBAA9gBmUDoAumTeZhbWtgAGACRIAkH0UAAKdBBBfKYiSYb5yTipdEYUQTl5cVAA-FDeZDgQAG70wiLuMP7BoWHiaJLQAIIcAPJ0AHKE0IiyCsqqmlowBljEjugS4CMcLvOKKuraq9gcWJtoQA)

Comment: Just a note - this works but it's a substring, not exactly a fuzzy match. Which is fine, it's what OP asked for. It's just that OP called it "fuzzy" but then described an exact substring match.